# I need specific placeholders to address specific types of jobs

Tags: input, placeholder, react-native-ios

This is the code I currently have. I need to change it so that a specific placeholder corresponds to the specific job type such as ride or service.  Ex) on the job type rides only a placeholder that corresponded to a ride would be displayed. The problem with the current code is that all placeholders are displayed randomly throughout each job type.

```
class NewJobInfo extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'What do you need?'
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    const placeholders = [
      'Pick up at Great Neck Library and drop me off at Roosevelt     field mall.',
      'Steak burrito, white rice, pinto beans, pico de gallo, hot salsa, cheese, guac, lettuce.',
      'Clean 3 rooms in my dorm. Common room, and bedrooms please vacuum.',
      'I want someone to wait in line at Kith, for the new yeezys’         'Venti caramel macchiato, extra hot, skim milk, extra foam.'
    ]

    this.state = {
      placeholder: placeholders[Math.floor(Math.random() *     placeholders.length)]
    }
  }

  render = () =>
    <Components.FormContainer
      caption="Be as descriptive as possible."
      buttonTitle="Next"
      onSubmit={this.submit}
      valid={this.isValid()}
    >
      <Components.TextInput
        title="Any notes?"
        value={this.props.job.description}
        valid={this.isValid()}
        onChangeText={this.save}
        onSubmitEditing={this.submit}
        placeholder={this.state.placeholder}
        height={100}
        multiline={true}
        maxLength={500}
        autoFocus={true}
        returnKeyType="next"
        last={true}
      />
    </Components.FormContainer>
```

Comment: My attempt to fix this was.        Placeholder:   placeholders[this.props.job.type === ‘ride’ , 0 || this.props.job.type === ‘delivery’, 1 || this.props.job.type === ‘service’, 2]